# Starting Chromium with switches in file?

Tags: linux, chromium

I am running chromium on linux and need to find a way to put all of the startup flags into a file instead of pushing them through the startup command

e.g: 
***chromium --disable-pinch --disable-sync http://URL***

is there a way to have these flags or "Switches" in a config file or something so flags can be added and removed in a central location.

any tips or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The classic way to do this is to create a simple shell script like `chromium-custom.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
chromium --disable-pinch --disable-sync "$@"
```

Then

```
chmod +x chromium-custom.sh
./chromium-custom.sh --extra-parameter http://URL
```